# Picking images from gallery (SD Card) on my app… ¿How to allow only max 500kb photos?

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, android-gallery

**WHAT I HAVE DONE NOW:** 
i am picking images on my app with android, and showing them on a ImageView of my layout, and sometimes i got an exception `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget`. This happens when the photos are higher than 500kb.

**WHAT I NEED TO DO (AND I DONT KNOW HOW TO DO IT):**
then, what i want to do is to allow the user only to select photos of maximum 500kb. And if the user selects a photo Higher than 500kb, then, my app should show a toast telling the user that only can select photos of max 500kb.... ¿how to do it?

this is my code:

```
changeImageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_SELECT_IMAGE);
            }
        }); 



protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) { 
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent); 

        switch(requestCode) {
        case 1:
        {
            setResult(1);
            finish();    
        }
        case ACTIVITY_SELECT_IMAGE:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){  
                Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();

                selectedPhoto = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
                //profileImage.setImageBitmap(selectedPhoto);
                profileImage.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(selectedPhoto, 80, 80, false));
            }
        }
    }
```

profileImage is a ImageView of my layout. and i use scaled butmap to resice the image to 80x80

please give me some help to do that, im searching on google and i can't find nothing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't you just use some standard Java to get the file size, then check against your limit?

```
private long getFileSize(String path) {
    File file = new File(path);
    if (file.exists() && file.isFile()) {
        return file.length();
    } else {
        return 0L;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Why do you hate your users so much? You are asking the wrong question... you don't need to cap the file size *at all*. It's the decompressed image size that's the problem, and you can control that.

Use the version of `BitmapFactory.decodeFile()` which takes a `BitmapFactory.Options` parameter, and then set the `inSampleSize` field of the options parameter to an appropriate value (2 or 4 or something). You may even want to use `inJustDecodeBounds` first to work out a reasonable value.

Comment: @AndroidUser99: This is the correct way to do it. Don't limit your users to small images. You can load verty big files this way without memory issues.

Comment: @reuben Scratton @ Savvas Dalkitsis if we decrease size of all the selected images then what will be the maximum number of images a user can select?